# Calling a method the first time passing a variable works fine, the second time the variable used is undefined

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have the following test code where I'm having trouble with the method `programs.selectPupil`

```
const programs = new require('../actions/programs.action')

describe('Batch Enroller tests', () => {
    const batchEnrollerChildId = 43607
    const batchEnrollerChildName = 'Child, Batch Enroller'

    it.only('Enroll and Unenroll student', () => {
        const programsTable = [['Universal Program', 'Universal Group', 'Universal', '$0.00'],
                               ['Custom Program', 'Custom Group', 'Custom', '$100.00'],
                               ['Monthly Program', 'Monthly Group', 'Monthly', '$50.00'], 
                               ['Monthly Dynamic Program', 'Monthly Group', 'Monthly Dynamic', '$10.00']]
        programs.goToProgramsPage()
        programs.openBatchEnrollerTab()
        programs.selectPupil(batchEnrollerChildId, batchEnrollerChildName)
        programs.selectPrograms(programsTable)
        programs.checkProgramTable(programsTable)
        programs.enroll()
        programs.goToProgramsPage()
        programs.openBatchEnrollerTab()
        programs.selectPupil(batchEnrollerChildId, batchEnrollerChildName)
        programsTable.forEach(function(program) {
            const programName = program[0] 
            programs.isProgramSelected(programName)
        })
        programs.checkProgramTable(programsTable)
        programs.unenroll()
    })
```

The method is defined here:

```
const pupilsList = 'pupils_list'
const selectProgramField = '[value="Select program"]'

export function clickPupilCheckbox(childId) {
    cy.get(`[value="${childId}"]`)
      .parent()
      .click()
}

export function selectPupil(childId, childName) {
    cy.get(`[href="#${pupilsList}"]`).click()
      .parent()
      .should('have.class', 'active')
    cy.get(`[id="${pupilsList}"]`).should('be.visible')
    cy.get(`[data-id="${childId}"]`)
      .as('childName')
      .should('have.text', childName)
    clickPupilCheckbox(childId)
    cy.get('@childName')
      .parent()
      .should('have.class', 'selected_pupils')
}
```

On the first call of `programs.selectPupil` it works as expected
`` cy.get(`[data-id="${childId}"]`) `` = `` cy.get(`[data-id="43607"]`) ``
and
`.should('have.text', childName)` = `.should('have.text', 'Child, Batch Enroller')`

[cypress log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80YNj.png)

The second time the values of `childId` and `childName` are undefined.

[cypress log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvt4O.png)

```
Console was cleared
index.656179c6.js:99332 Command:   assert
index.656179c6.js:99332 Message:   expected [data-id="undefined"] to have text undefined, but the text was ''
index.656179c6.js:99332 Error:     AssertionError: expected '[data-id="undefined"]' to have text undefined, but the text was ''
```

I'd like to know why this happens and how can I solve it.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:** I'm using Cypress 10.10.0.

Comment: This is impossible to debug without seeing the code it's testing, could you please add that here?

Comment: @MichaelC I don't see how the elements I'm interacting with in the DOM are relevant here. The main issue is not that the element is not being found, but that the assertion is done expecting `undefined` instead of the value of the variable `childId`.

Comment: what @MichaelC said. One way around this might be to put `const programs = new require('../actions/programs.action')` inside your test so that you get a new instance of `programs` each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The function `unenroll()` uses function `selectPupil()` but I wasn't passing the variables it requires.

```
export function unenroll(childId, childName) {
    cy.contains('button', 'Unenroll').click()
    clickYesAlertPopup()
    goToProgramsPage()
    openBatchEnrollerTab()
    selectPupil(childId, childName)
    cy.get(selectProgramField)
      .parent()
      .siblings('.search-choice')
      .should('not.exist')
}
```